# how to instantiate a class while jboss startup

Tags: java, jboss

I would like to instantiate my own java class (One time only) when the time of startup of JBOSS 5 and i will use that object until i shut down the jboss.

How can it be possible to instantiate.

Comment: is it a different reqiurement from a servletcontextlistener?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement your class with the [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface , which make your class able to receive notifications from the application server (i.e JBoss) when it starts and shut-downs .

For example:

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

            /**This method will run when the web application starts***/
           public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            /**Put your codes inside , it will run when JBoss starts ***/
           }

}
```

Then register your `MyServletContextListener` in the `web.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"> 
    <listener>
             <listener-class>com.abc.xyz.MyServletContextListener </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Package the application in the format of `WAR` and deploy it into the JBoss. When the JBoss starts , the `contextInitialized()` in the `MyServletContextListener` will run too.

Comment: thanks Ken Chen,

Is there any other way without creating war file,

Because mine is not a web application.

My thought is to create a single instance of the class and i can use across the application. (singleton.)

Comment: I am not sure , may be you have a look about `JMX` and `MBeans` .I don't know if they are helpful in your situation . See http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Custom+JMX+MBeans+in+JBoss and http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t49130.html Good luck