# Java: execute method when .war file is deployed

Tags: java

I want to execute some methods as soon as the .war file is deployed by Tomcat or JBoss, how can I do it?

I tried `ServletContextListener` but it's not working. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610370/jboss-tomcat-deploy-listener. That should solve your problem. From the original answer: "Did you look at JBoss JMX API? Among others there is a MainDeployer MBean that lets you manage deployments, it has a method listIncompletelyDeployed() which you can call to check what's not yet deployed. A ListenerServiceMBeanSupport allows you to subscribe for JMX notifications.

Well I cannot give you an exact solution, but poking around the JMX may bring you what you need."

Comment: Why not just use a servlet's initialiser?

Comment: `ServletContextListener` should do the trick. What problems did you encounter? Did you add the `@WebListener` annotation?

Comment: @f_puras yes I do, it works with Tomcat but not with JBoss

Comment: Don't know much about JBoss, so I cannot help with your problem. Did you check [how to instantiate a class while jboss startup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8147454/1606632)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I resolved this, this works with JBoss:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class InitializerEjb {

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    SMTPServer smtp_server = SMTPServer.getInstance();
    smtp_server.start();
  }   
}
```

And this works with Tomcat:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

   @WebListener
    public class Initializer implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public final void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
            SMTPServer smtp_server = SMTPServer.getInstance();
            smtp_server.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding your methods in a Servlet and then run it on startup

In your  **Web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.your.domain.YourServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```